# How can I get user input in my assembly bootloader?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, boot

I'm working on a assembly bootloader. I need help with getting input from the user. I use such code to print on the screen (in `start`). In `getInput`, I tried to get input from user but has not been worked. So, how could I do it?

```
org 0x7C00
BITS 16

start:
    cli                ; Disable interrupts
mov si, bootMsg1   ; Point SI to message
mov ah, 0x0E     ; Indicate BIOS we're going to print chars
.loop lodsb       ; Loads SI to AL
or al,al      ; Checks if the end of string
jz seperate
or al,al
jz halt   ; Jump to halt at the end
int 0x10      ; Otherwise, call interrupt for printing the char
jmp .loop     ; Next iteration of loop

...
getInput:
    cli
mov ah, 08 ; Indicate BIOS to get input
int 21h
mov ah,02
mov DL,AL
int 21h
MOV AH,4Ch   ; Function to exit
    MOV AL,00    ; Return 00
    INT 21h



halt: hlt ; CPU command to halt the execution
bootMsg1:   db "Slight Bootloader 1, Welcome!",13,10     ; Message
bootMsg2: db"------------",13,10
```

Comment: Int 21h is a DOS interrupt, which is only available if you run DOS. In a bootloader you are restricted to BIOS interrupts. See [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) for a better approach.

Comment: If you are new to assembly, it might be easier to start with writing DOS programs because the API is richer and because the environment has less restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Int 16h/AH=00h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm).
Some output as `Int 21h/AH=08h`.

[`Int 16h` has input utilities, `Int 10h` has output (video) utilities](http://ctyme.com/intr/int.htm).

---

Example.
Wait for the user to press a key and then "reboot".

```
BITS 16

xor ax, ax
int 16h

int 19h

TIMES 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0aa55h
```

Comment: Didn't work, how can I do it? Nothing happened again. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Note: I use VirtualBox o test and I captured keyboard/mouse with guest(so bootloader)

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri See the updated answer for a minimal example. Tested with VirtualBox. Remember to setup your booting environment correctly, the example is only mean to demonstrate `int 16h/ah=00h` works.

Comment: I need another thing. I need to get which key did the user press. How can I get it as a string value?

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri `int 16h/ah=00h` returns in `ax` the scancode of the key and its translation in ASCII according to the bios keyboard layout. If you search this site you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: The link didn't appear. Can you send the link again?

Comment: I checked the interrupt jump table, so it seems BIOS is more functional than I think. Because there are lots of possibilities for each interrupt.

Comment: Buti I still wonder something. You can input unicode characters using Alt+Numpad numbers. What would they return for al(ascii character) and ah(bios scan code)? Then, how would I identify it?

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri The `alt+XXX` functionality comes from the OS. At the hardware level each key (but the function key) send a scancode. The BIOS does a primitive translation using CP437 (IIRC) but it doesn't interpret `alt+xxx`. You can get the status of the special keys (`alt`, `ctrl`, etc) if you want to do it your self. If you press `alt+x`, for example, it'd be like pressing `x` alone. One exception is `CTRL+ALT+DEL` that is used by the BIOS to reboot.

Comment: I used a print function to print something but with this code, it doesn't work. What to do?

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri Debug it. Use Google. If everything fails, ask a new question.

Comment: I could solve it. My program works perfectly. For first, I switched to 32 bit assembly from 16 bit assembly. And I started a new kernel code. So, finally I'm okay. I'm currently trying to use C.